# Factoring a given polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I am trying to factor the polynomial
$$(a-1)x^2 + a^2xy+(a+1)y^2.$$
The  problem previous to it in the book uses the method of factoring a polynomial of the form
$$ax^2  + bx +c$$
by inspection, and the problem following it uses a formula related to cubes (I thought it's best you know). That said, I began by multiplying the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y$, but that did not yield something good.So I started again by taking $ax$, $x$, and $y$ as common, and that yielded nothing good. I would show some of my other work, but that would seem way too messy without proper formatting.

Comment: Then format it properly.

Comment: @dfeuer,hard,as I haven't got the necessary tool to do so on android.

Comment: yes you do. Just view the desktop site instead of the mobile one to get your posts to preview properly--nothing is required but a browser supporting Javascript and either CSS *or* SVG *or* MathML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Convince yourself that it's going to be $$(rx+sy)(tx+uy)$$ where $r$, $s$, $t$, and $u$ are going to have formulas involving $a$.
2. Note that $$rt=a-1,\quad su=a+1$$
3. How can you get two things that multiply to $a-1$? Don't look for anything really fancy; what are the simplest possibilities?
4. Same question for $a+1$.
5. Now you have some possibilities for $r$, $s$, $t$, and $u$; see which combination gives you the right coefficient for $xy$. 
   One will soon note that r=a-1 and u=a+1 works fine.Putting the values gives us the result required.Hence,we get,
   (ax-x+y)(x+ay+y)

Comment: Thanks for the hint.it helped.

Comment: Good. If you want to write up and post a complete answer, you can do that.

Comment: What,edit yours or create one by my own?

Comment: I had in mind writing up your own, but suit yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Look first at the coefficient of $xy$, $a^2$. The simplest way to get this from existing coefficients is $(a+1)(a-1)+1$. So one factor should contain $(a-1)x$ and the other should contain $(a+1)y$. Then the other terms need to have coefficient one to make the $xy$ coefficient correct in the product. That this all works out so nicely is deliberate, because generally such expressions will not factor nicely.

Comment: Thanks for putting it nicely.